# Run method for all values in Array at once

Tags: java, methods, arraylist

I am currently trying to run multiple methods of the same method at the same time. Right now it is only doing one at a time and then sleeping once it loops through all of them. I need it to do all the values in the array at the same time via the method. Here is my current code:

```
public static void checkTimer(TS3Api api) {
    for (String keys : admins) {
        //What I need: Check Groups for all values in string AT THE SAME TIME
            checkGroup(api, keys);
    }
            try {
                //Sleep for 10 second
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Do nothing
            }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to run them at the same time, you will need to create one thread per each key and execute them at the same time.  Depending on how long `checkGroup` method takes to execute, it may still not be at the same time though.

Comment: Adding to @AleksG comment, `checkGroup` must also be thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Thread.sleep(10000) causes the current thread to sleep for 10 seconds.  This would be the primary thread.  You have not split off any threads from the primary one, so this is working as you wrote it.

Take a look through the Java documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

There are some examples of splitting off threads.  This should get you on your way to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 you can write something like:

```
admins.parallelStream().forEach(keys -> checkGroup(api, keys));
```

The number of items it will do in parallel are system dependent, however. In any case, it is unlikely you can do all of them in parallel unless your system has at least as many processors as there are items in `admins`, no matter what approach you take.